# Readthedocs is not serving my documentation

Tags: read-the-docs

I'm working on serving the [doxygen documentation](http://genn-team.github.io/genn/documentation/4/html/index.html) for our C++ project on readthedocs so it gets built automatically and documentation for all versions is available.

I'm using [doxyrest](https://github.com/vovkos/doxyrest) to convert doxygen XML output to RST and this build fine both on my local machine and on readthedocs but, while I can download the pdf and the zipped html versions of the documentation off readthedocs, I just get the [maze thing](https://genn.readthedocs.io/en/readthedocs2/) when I try and read it online.

Here is my [docs directory](https://github.com/genn-team/genn/tree/readthedocs2/docs)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this happens if your conf.py is in docs/ rather than docs/source